# Let $f$ be continuous. If $f(x) = 0 \implies f$ is strictly increasing at $x$, then $f$ has at most one root.

Tags: real-analysis, continuity, solution-verification, roots

This is similar to [this question I asked yesterday](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3747853/is-fx-0-implies-fx-0-a-sufficient-condition-for-uniqueness-of-roots). I just need someone to check my proof (or offer an alternative proof) of the following statement

> Let $f : \mathbb R \rightarrow \mathbb R: x \mapsto f(x)$ be a continuous function. If $f(x) = 0 \implies f$ is strictly increasing on an open neighbourhood of $x$, then $f$ as at most one root.

Here's my attempt at a proof by contradiction.

<s>Case 1.</s>  Let $x_1 < x_2$ be two roots <s>with no other root in (x_1,x_2)</s> . Since $f$ is strictly increasing on a neighbourhood of each root we can find $\delta > 0$ such that $f> 0$ on $(x_i,x_i+\delta)$ and $f<0$ on $(x_i-\delta,x_i)$.

Using the intermediate value theorem we can find another root $c$ somewhere between $x_1$ and $x_2$ <s>, a contradiction.</s>

<s>Case 2. By the first part we can always find a root of $f$ between any two given roots of $f$. Let x_1 < x_2 be two roots.</s>

We will show that $f = 0$ on $(x_1,x_2)$ which contradicts the fact that $f$ is strictly increasing at it's roots.

Let $\tilde x \in (x_1,x_2).$

Define $$x_1' = \sup \{ x \in [x_1,\tilde x] : f(x) = 0 \}$$
$$x_2' = \inf\{x \in [\tilde x,x_2]: f(x) = 0\}.$$

Since $x_i'$ is the $\inf$ (or $\sup$) of a bounded set we can find a sequence of roots wich converges to $x_i'$ so by continuity of $f$ we have $f(x_1') = f(x_2') = 0.$

Clearly $ x_1' \leq \tilde x \leq x_2'$ so we need only consider the two following cases

- If $\tilde x  = x_1'$ or $\tilde x = x_2'$ then $f(\tilde x) = 0.$
- If $\tilde x \in (x_1',x_2')$ then since $x_1'$ and $x_2'$ are roots we can find a new root $c$ in $(x_1',x_2')$. If $\tilde x \leq  c$ then we have a contradiction with the definition of $x_2'$ and similarly $c \leq \tilde x$ contradicts the definition of $x_1'$.

Therefore we must have $f(\tilde x) = 0.$

Therefore $f$ cannot have several roots since $f$ would then be equal to $0$ on an interval which contradicts the fact that $f$ is strictly increasing on a neighboorhood of it's roots.

Comment: You have the right idea, but you're being overly formal. Here is how I would write the proof:
Note a root implies you must pass from negative to positive or vise-versa. Suppose we have some root of $f$, namely $x_1$. By hypothesis, $f$ approaches $x_1$ from below, so $f(x) > 0$ in a right neighborhood of $x_1$. Then there can be no root $x_2$ to the right of $x_1$ since $f$ would have to approach $x_2$ from above, violating our hypothesis. Thus, given any root, there can be no more roots to the right. If there were two roots then one root must violate this, so we are done

Comment: If you really want to formalize what I wrote, the following should suffice: To prove that in a neighborhood of a root one has to pass from positive to negative or vise-versa you can use the intermediate value theorem or something akin to it (this is a fairly basic result), and the "approaching from above/below" can be formalized in terms of inequalities on $f$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks correct, except for one thing. In Case 1, you wrote “Let $x_1<x_2$ be two roots with no other root in $(x_1,x_2)$.” What you wrote after that is fine. But then, in Case 2, you wrote “By the first part we can always find a root of $f$ between any two given roots of $f$”. But in Case 1 you had an extra assumption, namely that there is no root between $x_1$ and $x_2$. So, you cannot apply Case 1 to **any** two given roots of $f$.

My suggestion then is this: do your proof in two steps:

1. prove that between any two distinct roots of $f$ there has to be another root;
2. use this to prove what you want to prove.

Comment: Thanks for your comments. I've edited my attempt It should be correct now.

Comment: It looks correct now.